# Cat knocked milk into desktop gaming pc

Tags: water-damage

About 15 minutes ago my cat jumped on my desk and knocked my glass of milk which was about 1/6 as full into my desktop.

- My reaction time was quick and I managed to rip all of the cables out of the computer, minus the monitors.
- However, before I had a chance to remove the cables, I noticed the monitors has already gone black.
- I didn't and still don't know if it shut down.
- After that I flipped the thing upside down and moved it into my kitchen.
- Then I removed both removable sides of the case and began wiping away the milk with a few paper towels.
- Then, I got some of those dust removers and used it as WD-40 to blow some of the milk away/into areas I could get it.
- At the moment, it is upside down in an air conditioned room, drying. I'm scared as it is a $1000 dollar PC and the software and stuff on it is about $1500.

I don't have the money to replace it at the moment so any help is appreciated.

Things I know are affected:

- Motherboard
- Graphics card
- Possibly RAM

Things I think aren't affected:

- Power supply < haven't opened because I am scared I will be shocked.
- Hard drive

Every thing else I don't know about about.

Comment: I would add a photo but since I'm restricted to an iPad and this site isn't mobile friendly, I can't.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Go to sleep. Things like this are best done after some time to chill out, and a good strong mug of coffee

Answer (score -1):

There is a good chance that your components survived.

Just let everything dry out. A good idea would be to take the entire pc apart and let it dry for a few days before actually using it again.

Just don't plug it in or give it any kind of power!

Comment: Leftover mil will go source. Acid like (though mild).  Might want to clean that *somehow*.

Comment: It will also STINK!